# Yes / no questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request

We got a little discussion at this post: [Amplifier Vpp calculation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/57184/amplifier-vpp-calculation). The Photon says yes/no questions aren't good for SE and I agree. They aren't right? (1st question)

If you agree, where is it in the FAQ? I can't find it. (2nd question)

If it isn't there, should it be added? (3rd question)

Comment: Maybe I should have said "yes/no answers are not a good fit for StackExchange" ... but problem was that OP was asking for a yes/no answer, not that answerers were giving yes/no hit-and-run answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the real issue with that question is that it is *too localized.* Yes, it just happens to also be a yes or no question, but that itself shouldn't dictate whether a question gets closed.

You are correct that the policy on the Yes/No questions is not in the FAQ. However, there has been some discussion about Yes/No questions on Stack Overflow Meta (which, as few people seem to remember, serves as the unofficial FAQ for the entire Stack Exchange network - but that's a rant for another day). For example:

- [Policy towards "Is there a way/tool to ..." questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155562/policy-towards-is-there-a-way-tool-to-questions)
- [Should I flag answers consisting only of "No" or "Yes"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110165/should-i-flag-answers-consisting-only-of-no-or-yes)
- [Ought objective yes/no questions about the existence of a project etc be construed as "poll questions"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161766/ought-objective-yes-no-questions-about-the-existence-of-a-project-etc-be-constru?lq=1)

The general consensus is that Yes/No questions are ok as long as an answer can be provided that is more than simply **Yes** or **No**.

**Added**

If someone can take a Yes/No question and turn it into something constructive and useful for future visitors, then I say go for it. After all, some people here have a habit of [answering a question that is different from what was asked](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1428/2473) anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Correct.
2. It isn't.
3. Nope.

Comment: 4th question: why not? ;-)

Comment: @CamilStaps Because.

Comment: May I summarize? 1. Yes 2. No 3. No.

Comment: I disagree with the blanket statement that Yes/No questions are not appropriate for the site. As with everything, I say *it depends.* If a Yes/No question can be answered with the addition of *why*, then it's a valuable addition to the site.

Comment: For those that might not realize, when W5VO is responding to @CamilStaps he is being tongue in cheek(sarcastic) and using very short answers with no explanation to show that they are not helpful.

Comment: @Kortuk: I think we can all appreciate the humor, but some users might actually believe these answers since they are coming from a diamond mod.

Comment: @SimpleCoder That is why I added a disclaimer. :)

Comment: @Kortuk: Hmm, I guess I did just restate what you said - never mind :)