# FAQ tag not about main site FAQ

Tags: support, feature-request

It appears to be that the [FAQ tag](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) on meta is used for the questions that are most frequently asked on the meta site. What if I want to post something about the [FAQ page](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/faq) on the main site, like [Yes / no questions](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2638/yes-no-questions)? Is that possible? If it isn't, can it be added?

So can there be a new tag `main-faq` or `about-the-faq`?

Comment: This question doesn't make a lot of sense - Do you expect special treatment for questions that regard the FAQ?

Comment: No, I want normal treatment for them, so that we can use the `faq` tag for questions about the main faq. We cannot tag questions about the main faq now.

Comment: New tag: "about-the-faq".

Comment: Oh, ok, so you want a tag created for the site's FAQ. I forget the policy about tag creation on Meta sites for non-mods.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I want, @ThePhoton. I updated my question.

Comment: I think we need a Meta-Meta-EE site for questions about the Meta site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that certain tags should be created as mentioned in the question. The tags could be :

- `main-faq` or `site-faq` : Questions about the [main FAQ](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/faq)
- `meta-faq` : Questions about [faq](/questions/tagged/faq)
- `faq` : The actual [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) questions on Meta

These are similar to tags used on [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags)

Comment: I totally agree, but am not sure about `meta-faq`. Could you give a usage example?

Comment: @CamilStaps That would really depend on there being some questions in meta being tagged faq first http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq Additionally, you could see this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta-faq There are some questions there.

Comment: Oh, wait, I see. @Kortuk, why did you set this to [meta-tag:status-declined]? I'd say this is a good idea.

Comment: @CamilStaps Clarification, are you referring to [tag:faq] or /faq (http://electronics.stackexchange.com/faq) in your feature-request ?

Comment: /faq, so what will be `main_faq` in your solution.

Answer (score 1):

The [faq](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) is a special tag for questions *on the site* that are asked frequently. It cannot be reporposed. Additionally, only a small portion of the actual main site FAQ is editable, primarily the "[What kind of questions can I ask here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/faq)" section.

Comment: Sorry for any misunderstanding, what I meant was can there be a new tag about the main FAQ? I updated my question accordingly.